# Swift: Grouping Futures while making them wait util the previous Promise is fulfilled using Combine

Tags: ios, swift, macos, combine

Suppose we've three `Futures` each wrapping an asynchronous call & each depends on the previous `Promise` to be fulfilled. Ideally, I'd like to have all these get executed only when the subscriber is attached. How do we get this going using Combine?

```
    private func future1() -> Future<Bool, Error> {
        return Future { [weak self] promise in
            self?.task1 { result in
                promise(result)
            }
        }
    }

    private func future2() -> Future<Bool, Error> {
        return Future { [weak self] promise in
            self?.task2 { result in
                promise(result)
            }
        }
    }

    private func future3() -> Future<Bool, Error> {
        return Future { [weak self] promise in
            self?.task3 { result in
                promise(result)
            }
        }
    }


    future1()..
    future2()..
    future3()..
    .sink {..}
```

Comment: What's the expected value that the subscriber would receive? Is it just the result of `future3`? And does future2 depend on the value emitted by future1 and so forth?

Comment: Yes, the subscriber should only be expecting value from the future3. And yes, future2 depends on the promise of future1. It either fails, the subscriber should be getting an error, and the pipeline should be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

`Future` executes its closure synchronously, so it's usually wrapped in a `Deferred`, which waits for a subscription before it executes its closure.

This sounds like exactly what you'd need to do.

```
private func future1() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> {
   Deferred { 
      Future { [weak self] promise in
         self?.task1 { result in
            promise(result)
         }
      }
   }
   .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Then, you can use `.flatMap` to stagger each publisher:

```
future1()
   .flatMap { result1 in
       // do something with result1
       return future2()
   }
   .flatMap { result2 in
       // do something with result2
       return future3()
   }
   .sink(...)
```